# Benefits and drawbacks of making all functions in main.c static?

Tags: c

I have heard that, when you have just 1 (main.c) file (or use a "unity build"), there are benefits to be had if you make all your functions static.

I am kind of confused why this (allegedly) isn't optimized by default, since it's not probable that you will include main.c into another file where you will use one of its functions.

I would like to know the benefits and dangers of doing this before implementing it.

Example:

**main.c**

```
static int my_func(void){ /*stuff*/ }

int main(void) {
    my_func();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "since it's not probable that you will include main.c into another file where you will use one of its functions." Assuming you are talking about including it into a larger project instead of including it in another file (which is generally not a good idea). Where did you get the idea that it is unlikely to use functions of one file in another file? Main.c is no different from any other .c file.

Comment: The primary benefit of static functions is that the compiler can (and will) aggressively inline them when it knows there is no other code that can call the function.  I've had error messages from four levels of inlined function calls (three qualifying “inlined from” lines) on occasion.  It's staggering what a compiler will do!

Comment: General rule: Anytime you can write code that says the use of something is limited, do it. Value will not be modified? Make it `const`. Name only needs to be used in a certain section? Declare it in the innermost enclosing scope. Name does not need to be linked externally? Make it `static`. Every limitation both shrinks the window for a bug to be created and may remove complications that interfere with optimization.

Comment: FWIW: my rule of thumb is that every function should be static until it is known that it will be called from code in another file.  When it is known that it will be used elsewhere, it should be declared in a header file that is included both where the function is defined and where it is used.  The `main` function is always called from the startup code so it is never static.  Any function defined in the same file as a `main()` function that is not conditionally compiled (a test program for a library function) cannot be reused by other programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have various chunks of wisdom in the comments, assembled here into a Community Wiki answer.

[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) noted:

> The primary benefit of static functions is that the compiler can (and will) aggressively inline them when it knows there is no other code that can call the function. I've had error messages from four levels of inlined function calls (three qualifying “inlined from” lines) on occasion. It's staggering what a compiler will do!

and:

> FWIW: my rule of thumb is that every function should be `static` until it is known that it will be called from code in another file. When it is known that it will be used elsewhere, it should be declared in a header file that is included both where the function is defined and where it is used.  (Similar rules apply to file scope variables — aka 'global variables'; they should be `static` until there's a proven need for them elsewhere, and then they should be declared in a header too.)
>
> The `main()` function is always called from the startup code, so it is never static. Any function defined in the same file as an unconditionally compiled `main()` function cannot be reused by other programs.  (Library code might contain a conditionally compiled test program for the library function(s) defined in the source file — most of my library code has `#ifdef TEST` / …test program… / `#endif` at the end.)

[Eirc Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) generalized on that:

> General rule: Anytime you can write code that says the use of something is limited, do it. Value will not be modified? Make it `const`. Name only needs to be used in a certain section? Declare it in the innermost enclosing scope. Name does not need to be linked externally? Make it `static`. Every limitation both shrinks the window for a bug to be created and may remove complications that interfere with optimization.